# Creating cookie when using odata and web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

How do I set a cookie when using Web api 2 and odata. I am new to this api and traditionally I used the context.Response but it does not seem to be avaliable here.

This is a part of my controller code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Order Order)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    context.Orders.Add(Order);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created(Order);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own DelegatingHandler to add the cookie you need into the response.

Check the part "Example: Set and Retrieve Cookies in a Message Handler":

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies

For how to insert a message handler, check this:"Per-Route Message Handlers"

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `IHttpActionResult` class there's a function within it `Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);`

You can use that function to return the `HttpResponseMessage` and add cookies to the response message.

I would make another class that implements `IHttpActionResult` similar to this:

```
public class OrderResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    Order _order;
    HttpRequestMessage _request;

    public OrderResult(Order order, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _order = value;
        _request = request;
    }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(_value),
            RequestMessage = _request
        };

        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", "6789");
        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;

        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

You will need to adjust your controller code to call this new class. e.g.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Order Order)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    context.Orders.Add(Order);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new OrderResult(Order, request /* not sure how you'll get the request in this scope*/);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Created(Order) is a part of the odata library, System.Web.Http.OData.dll (which I am new too), so I would like too keep it somehow.